Need to Understand Why Docker Stopped Working?
I have several Docker containers running on a Raspberry Pi 4b, they have all suddenly stopped working and I don't know why... If I try to update my containers I get this error
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Now I have checked Docker is running using docker context ls which gives me this
NAME        DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                     KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRATOR
default *   Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock                         swarm
rootless    Rootless mode                             unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock                         
Warning: DOCKER_HOST environment variable overrides the active context. To use a context, either set the global --context flag, or unset DOCKER_HOST environment variable.

I have also run docker info which gives me this
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.17.1)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.29.7)

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info

and sudo docker info for more detail
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.17.1)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.29.7)

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 20.10.24+dfsg1
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 1.6.20~ds1-1+b1
 runc version: 1.1.5+ds1-1+deb12u1
 init version: 
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8
 Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: aarch64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 3.703GiB
 Name: raspberrypi
 ID: <REDACTED>
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support

I have checked that docker is running, as well as Docker.Socket and all seems fine. I've run
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock  http://localhost/_ping; echo with returns OK.
I've run sudo systemctl status docker
  docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-10-17 03:00:43 BST; 5h 53min ago
TriggeredBy: â docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 1219 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 9
        CPU: 9.933s
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             ââ1219 /usr/sbin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Oct 17 03:00:39 raspberrypi dockerd[1219]: time="2024-10-17T03:00:39.955431599+01:00" level=info msg="[core] Channel Connectivity change to READY" module=>
Oct 17 03:00:41 raspberrypi dockerd[1219]: time="2024-10-17T03:00:41.370905561+01:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
Oct 17 03:00:41 raspberrypi dockerd[1219]: time="2024-10-17T03:00:41.605617635+01:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find memory controller"
Oct 17 03:00:41 raspberrypi dockerd[1219]: time="2024-10-17T03:00:41.616783561+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Oct 17 03:00:42 raspberrypi dockerd[1219]: time="2024-10-17T03:00:42.642084690+01:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP addr>
Oct 17 03:00:42 raspberrypi dockerd[1219]: time="2024-10-17T03:00:42.810640394+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Oct 17 03:00:43 raspberrypi dockerd[1219]: time="2024-10-17T03:00:43.579322782+01:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=5d6db84 graphdriver(s)=overlay>
Oct 17 03:00:43 raspberrypi dockerd[1219]: time="2024-10-17T03:00:43.580233301+01:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"

and also sudo systemctl status docker.socket which gives me
  docker.socket - Docker Socket for the API
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-10-17 03:00:26 BST; 5h 55min ago
   Triggers: â docker.service
     Listen: /run/docker.sock (Stream)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 3909)
        CPU: 2ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.socket

Oct 17 03:00:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting docker.socket - Docker Socket for the API...
Oct 17 03:00:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Listening on docker.socket - Docker Socket for the API.

All looks good, can anyone help me please, as I can't even pull Docker Containers either...?

It looks like your Docker CLI expects the daemon to live at unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock but your actual daemon is at /var/run/docker.sock. Have you had Docker installed in rootless mode?

The docker context ls output suggests you have the $DOCKER_HOST environment variable set; does unsetting it help?  (This is consistent with the working sudo docker ... output, since sudo will reset the environment.)

So for my instance, it would seem that the DOCKER_HOST got set somehow, so a quick docker context use default indicated that DOCKER_HOST was set, so I just ran unset DOCKER_HOST, and everything sprang into life.
I found the offending DOCKER_HOST entry in my .bashrc file and removed it...
